# Проблема с созданием массива c++/cli

Tags: .net

Я СОВСЕМ НАЧИНАЮЩИЙ ! (чтоб не сильно критиковали,а доступно объяснили)
Написал простенькую программу - захват видео через OpenCV и его воспроизведение на pictureBox1.
Пытаюсь сделать раскадровку - создаю массив и каждый кадр в цикле завожу в него. Пробую извлечь конкретный кадр из массива в pictureBox2 - изображение не получаю.Какая-то информация в элементе массива есть - pictureBox2 меняет цвет - но конкретной картинки конкретного кадра нет.Если вместо заведения кадра в массив использую SAVE в файл - кадр записывается и отображается,а через массив не хочет.Может кто подскажет в чем проблема или ошибка.Привожу код:

```
#pragma endregion

        array<Image^>^img;

        Bitmap^myBitmap;
      bool Pause;

    int i;
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             img=gcnew array<Image^>(625);// определяю как i+1


                 CvCapture* capture;

      cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "C:\\Users\\валера\\Downloads\\dance.mpg");


     while(true){

          if(Pause!=true)
          {
           // получаем следующий кадр

              frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
                if( !frame ) {

                    break;

                }
                myBitmap = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame->width,frame->height,frame->widthStep, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)frame->imageData);  
            pictureBox1->Image = myBitmap;
             img[i]= pictureBox1->Image;


             label2->Text = i.ToString(); // показываю количество кадров  
        //if(i==3)
        //{
           // pictureBox1->Image->Save( "C:\\MyPics\\image11.bmp" );
        //}
            i++;


          }


                char c = cvWaitKey(40);
                if (c == 27) { // если нажата ESC - выходим
                        break;
                }
        }


     cvReleaseCapture( &capture );


       cvDestroyWindow("original");
             }


private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Pause=!Pause;
         }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             pictureBox2->Image=img[10];// выбираю произвольный индекс из массива,который хочу отобразить


             //pictureBox2->Image=Image::FromFile("C:\\MyPics\\image11.bmp");
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Все,вопрос закрыт,разобрался. Ведь в массиве хранится не сам image,а лишь ссылка на него. Но создаваясь в цикле image нигде не сохраняется ! Т.е. я пытаюсь ссылаться на НЕСУЩЕСТВУЮШИЙ объект.

Comment: Ставлю плюс, хотя это против правил форума, но на мой взгляд всегда нужно поддерживать людей, пытающихся самостоятельно разобраться в проблеме :)